# How to select data rows into columns w/out knowing all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Below is a table I have with some order details.

```
OrderID TypeID Amount
11148   1      900
11148   7      30
11148   6      75
12506   3      100
12506   4      60
16845   1      30
```

Is it possible to return something like this:

```
OrderID TypeID1 Amount1 TypeID2 Amount2 TypeID3 Amount3
11148   1       900     7       30      6       75    
12506   3       100     4       60      null    null
16845   1       30      null    null    null    null
```

I want to get results like this so I can join into another result set with other order information but I can only have one row per ID. I've been trying with a Pivot but it seems I need to know all the possible results for TYPEID and have that many columns instead of just the 3 for TYPEID and 3 for AMOUNT that I'm looking for.

Below is the Pivot table I know how to get to work but this is not desired because then I have columns for each ID type but I would rather have those in the rows too.

```
SELECT OrderID
    ,[1] as Amount1
    ,[2] as Amount2
    ,[3] as Amount3
    ,[4] as Amount4
    ,[5] as Amount5
    ,[6] as Amount6
    ,[7] as Amount7
FROM ( 
    SELECT ORDERID, TYPEID, AMOUNT
    FROM Order_Details
)x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AMOUNT)
    FOR TYPEID in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
)P

OrderID Amount1 Amount2 Amount3 Amount4 Amount5 Amount6 Amount7
11148   900     null    null    null    null    75      30   
12506   null    null    100     60      null    null    null
16845   30      null    null    null    null    null    null
```

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Thanks tdbeckett, Which code would you need to see? I don't have any code that gets me close to the desired result set. Do you want the pivot that doesn't work like I want?

Comment: We are here to help you debug and help with advanced concepts that you might be struggling with.  I'm not trying to be a jerk.  We aren't here to do your work for you, and from the post the you have provided it looks like you haven't done anything at all.

Comment: Hint: use a `PIVOT` to achieve this.

Comment: I know and I'm not thinking you are jerk. I appreciate the help. I literally didn't know what to post. I've updated with the Pivot I'm trying to manipulate. I don't think I'm understanding the Pivot concept when not using dates.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to make a self outer join combined with row_number over partition like:

```
select t1.OrderId as OrderID1, t1.TypeID as TypeID1, t1.Amount as Amount1,
t2.TypeID as TypeID2, t2.Amount as Amount2,
t3.TypeID as TypeID3, t3.Amount as Amount3 from 
(
SELECT OrderID, TypeID, Amount 
FROM (
select OrderID , TypeID, Amount ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID order by OrderID) AS RN
from tt
)Sub
WHERE rn = 1) t1 left join
(
SELECT OrderID, TypeID, Amount 
FROM (
select OrderID , TypeID, Amount ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID order by OrderID) AS RN
from tt
)Sub
WHERE rn = 2) t2 on t1.OrderID=t2.OrderID left join
(
SELECT OrderID, TypeID, Amount
FROM (
select OrderID , TypeID, Amount ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID order by OrderID) AS RN
from tt
)Sub
WHERE rn = 3) t3 on t1.OrderID=t3.OrderID;
```

[live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e49db/9/0)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Learning the Row_Number() helped me out a ton and set me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

by using cross apply and Row_number we can achieve same result

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (OrderID int, TypeID int, Amount int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (OrderID, TypeID, Amount)
VALUES
    (11148, 1, 900),
    (11148, 7, 30),
    (11148, 6, 75),
    (12506, 3, 100),
    (12506, 4, 60),
    (16845, 1, 30)
;



;with CTE As (
 select OrderID,[TypeID1],[TypeID2],[TypeID3] from (
 Select OrderID,
 val,
 COL + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS VARCHAR(1))RN  
    FROM @Table1 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('TypeID',TypeID))CS(Col,val))T
PIVOT (MAX(VAL) FOR RN IN ([TypeID1],[TypeID2],[TypeID3]))P )
,CTE2 AS (select OrderID,[Amount1],[Amount2],[Amount3] from (
 Select OrderID,
 val,
 COL + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS VARCHAR(1))RN  
    FROM @Table1 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Amount',Amount))CS(Col,val))T
PIVOT (MAX(VAL) FOR RN IN ([Amount1],[Amount2],[Amount3]))P)

select c.OrderID,c.TypeID1,cc.Amount1,c.TypeID2,cc.Amount2,c.TypeID3,cc.Amount3 from CTE C
LEFT JOIN CTE2 CC
ON c.OrderID = cc.OrderID
```

Comment: @mothra have you executed performance wise is much better comparing to other